# Can you play Star Citizen at the moment?

Tags: star-citizen

I played the demo update they released where you were in the hangar. Is that over? It's telling me that I need to have a game package. I searched their site and am still a little curious as to how you get into beta/alpha.

How much do you need to donate to get your hands on the game immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Star Citizen just released update 1.1, which means they have ended the free promotional period (certainly there will be more, as well as promo codes). As far as I can see from this [Link](https://robertsspaceindustries.com/pledge/game-packages), you need a ship which includes an Arena Commander pass.

I purchased a Mustang Beta, and still have access to Arena Commander in spite of my not having it listed with a pass. Don't tell anyone to fix it please.

Comment: lol. When is the beta for first person module coming? Should I start a new comment?

Comment: Short answer: stalled due to network matchmaking system rewrite. They are considering releasing an alpha as soon as they can make sure it wouldn't be miserable for players.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy modules separately to play the dog fighting.  From here https://robertsspaceindustries.com/pledge/extras?product_id=63